# Can we use "stand" as a verb in aviation?

Tags: airport, airport-operations

Is it correct to use "stand" as a verb and as an equivalent verb to "park" in the context of an airport?

Answer (score 3):

I've only ever heard it used as a noun.  You would never say "Stand your plane over there".  You'd say park it over by the xxxx stand.

Comment: Would it be possible to say: "The aircraft will stand at the gate until its departure time"?

Comment: I suppose you could. I'd just say "remain at the gate". If you said "stand at the gate" I'd understand it though.

Comment: One *"possibly"* could say all sorts of things and people could probably figure out what was meant, but I agree, that is simply not the way the word is used, at least in US aviation. Aircraft do not stand; they park, they sit, they remain, they stop, and sometimes they even go (ideally, close to on-time!), but I don't think I've ever heard of one that "stands" someplace.